# Confusing definition of Winch

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

The WordWeb dictionary defines ***Winch*** as:

> Lifting device consisting of a horizontal cylinder turned by a crank
>   on which a cable or rope winds

From the description I decipher that the rope winds on the crank but actually the rope winds on the cylinder, am I right or the WordWeb's sentence is correct ?

Please add/remove relevant/irrelevant tags.

Comment: The rope winds on the cylinder, yes. You're meant to take "a horizontal cylinder turned by a crank" as a discrete entity. This is a case where punctuation would make things clearer: "... a horizontal cylinder, turned by a crank, on which a cable or rope winds."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oxford Dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/winch):

winch
NOUN

1. A hauling or lifting device consisting of a rope or chain winding round a horizontal rotating drum, turned typically by a crank or by motor.

and from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winch)

winch (plural winches)

1. A machine consisting of a drum on an axle, a friction brake or ratchet and pawl, and a crank handle or prime mover (often an electric or hydraulic motor), with or without gearing, to give increased mechanical advantage when hauling on a rope or cable.
2. (nautical) A hoisting machine used for loading or discharging cargo, or for hauling in lines.

Much clearer explanations on both sites. Why use *WordWeb* when many free online (good quality) English dictionaries exist?